# Schur polynomial with integer values

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-polynomials

There is a way to characterize for which $x_1,...,x_d$ a Schur polynomial, that can be defined as
$$s_\lambda(x_1,...,x_d)=\sum_{T\in SSYT(\lambda)}x_1^{t_1}...x_d^{t_d}, $$
with the sum running over the semistandard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$, takes integer values? there is research along those lines?

Comment: You mean that for all $\lambda$ the value must be integer? For fixed $\lambda$ there hardly can be a characterization other than "this polynomial at this point takes an integer value".

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I Forgot to specify that I want to know when the specialization is an integer for some set of diagrams, but maybe not all of them.

Comment: Can you perhaps give an example of what you want? Say, a certain set of diagrams where you expect or already have a reasonable description?

Comment: If you want for all of them simultaneously, then that's equivalent to integrality in the other symmetric function bases, the m:s, e:s and h:s.